# Importing records from PostgreSQL to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, database-migration

Was wondering if anyone had any insight or recommended tools for exporting the records from a PostgreSQL database and importing them into a MySQL database. I believe the table structure is 100% identical.

Thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The command

```
pg_dump --data-only --column-inserts <database_name>
```

will generate SQL-standard-compliant INSERT statements with all column names listed and one VALUES clause per INSERT.   This is the most portable way of moving data from PostgreSQL to any other SQL database.

Comment: Before you import the SQL file into your database, run a `[bundle exec ]rake db:migrate` to create the tables and columns.

Answer (score 5):

Check out [SquirrelSQL](http://www.squirrelsql.org/), it can pump data from one database brand into another via the [DBCopy plugin](http://www.squirrelsql.org/index.php?page=plugins).  When the table structures are really identical it works quite well.

Answer (score 3):

There is a ruby app called Taps that will do it. I've used it before with great success:

http://adam.heroku.com/past/2009/2/11/taps_for_easy_database_transfers/